# declare generic parents statement in aspectj

Tags: aop, aspectj

Is it possible to use generic types with declare parents such that a class defined with generics implements an interface with the same generic types

i.e    `declare parents: AClass<Generic1,Generic2> implements`

```
AnInterface<Generic1,Generic2>
```

What I am saying is whether it is possible to pass the generic types of the child to parents

Answer (score 0):

Kind of. Check this out:

**Generic class:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class KeyValuePair<K,V> {
    private K key;
    private V value;

    KeyValuePair(K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public K getKey() { return key; }
    public V getValue() { return value; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "KeyValuePair [key=" + key + ", value=" + value + "]";
    }
}
```

**Generic interface:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public interface KeyValueComparator<K, V> {
    boolean equalsKey(K otherKey);
    boolean equalsValue(V otherValue);
}
```

**Aspect with ITD:**

The ITD (inter-type definition) makes sure that the class implements the interface and also gets method implementations for the interface at the same time.

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import de.scrum_master.app.KeyValuePair;
import de.scrum_master.app.KeyValueComparator;

public aspect InterfaceIntroductionAspect {
    declare parents : KeyValuePair implements KeyValueComparator;

    public boolean KeyValuePair.equalsKey(K otherKey) {
        return this.getKey().equals(otherKey);
    }

    public boolean KeyValuePair.equalsValue(V otherValue) {
        return this.getValue().equals(otherValue);
    }
}
```

**Driver application:**

Create two different types of class objects and try to cast them both to the introduced interface:

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        KeyValuePair<Integer, String> pair1 = new KeyValuePair<>(11, "eleven");
        System.out.println(pair1);
        KeyValueComparator<Integer, String> comparator1 = (KeyValueComparator<Integer, String>) pair1;
        System.out.println("equalsKey   = " + comparator1.equalsKey(12));
        System.out.println("equalsValue = " + comparator1.equalsValue("eleven"));

        KeyValuePair<String, Integer> pair2 = new KeyValuePair<>("twelve", 12);
        System.out.println(pair2);
        KeyValueComparator<String, Integer> comparator2 = (KeyValueComparator<String, Integer>) pair2;
        System.out.println("equalsKey   = " + comparator2.equalsKey("twelve"));
        System.out.println("equalsValue = " + comparator2.equalsValue(11));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
KeyValuePair [key=11, value=eleven]
equalsKey   = false
equalsValue = true
KeyValuePair [key=twelve, value=12]
equalsKey   = true
equalsValue = false
```